# Reporting tool in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Do we have any Reporting tool like jasper/birt to create the reports in Elixir, or any API that will help.

i tried searching on google, could not find any. Anyone here who can help.
Thanks

Comment: For people unfamiliar with jasper/birt - what do they do? What functionality are you looking for?

Comment: i am looking for a reporting tool or api, that will help me create reports in elixir. e.g. we have jasper in java, crystal reports in .net etc @nietaki

Comment: i need to send reports to my clients, i am using phoenix framework.

Comment: Please provide links to the tools you are mentioning. IIRC JasperReports goes directly onto the database. So what prohibits you from using it with your phoenix application?
Also what kind of reports do you want to generate? About your data, application usage? Node(s)?

Comment: nothing prohibits me to use Jasper. but i am in search of using reporting tool in Elixir, so that i code in Elixir, and dont have to use multiple servers. @Johannes

Comment: reports linked to payments. like purchase report, transactions etc. @Johannes

Comment: I may be wrong but I doubt there's any Elixir specific reporting engine.  Even if there is, asking for a recommendation of software tooling is off-topic on S O.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest generating PDF from html using something like https://github.com/gutschilla/elixir-pdf-generator

I am not aware of Jasper-like BI tools available in Elixir and I really doubt there will be one without major player open sourcing it.

However, with the tool like html->pdf renderer you can reuse quite a lot of your Phoenix contexts business logic and have report-specific markup.

I have plenty of experience of rending PDF out of HTML in microservice-based / SPA apps and I must say doing so from Elixir app/cluster will be much better.